# Merging matplotlib pie-charts into single figure

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a list "state" which looks as follows:

```
state = [{'success': 17, 'failed': 28}, {'success': 15, 'failed': 22}]
```

I am trying to generate pie-charts for each dictionary inside the list "state". I want to have one single chart (figure) containing both the pie-charts. Also I want to give the title of each pie-chart based on another dynamic list "pipeline_names":

```
pipeline_names = ['Pipeline1','Pipeline2'].
```

Pipeline1 should be title for first pie-chart and Pipeline2 should be title for second pie-chart

This is what I am trying, but I am getting two different charts instead of one figure containing two pie-charts. Can I get some help on this.

```
for k in range(len(state)):
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(6, 3))
    axs[k].pie(state[k].values(), labels=state[k].keys(), autopct'%.0f%%')
    axs[k].set_title(p for p in pipeline_names)
    plt.ylabel('Status in %')
    plt.xlabel('Pipeline')
    plt.savefig('Pipeline_Chart%03d.png'%(k))`
```

Comment: You could move `plt.subplots(....)` and `plt.savefig(...)` outside the `for` loop. Note that `plt.ylabel(...)` should be replaced by `axs[k].set_ylabel(...)` (and similar for `x`).  `axs[k].set_title(pipeline_names[k])` would set the title for the subplot you are drawing in that step of the loop.

Comment: Thanks JohanC, I was able to resolve my problem using your solution.